# Why is $k[x,y]$ not finitely generated as $k[x]$-module?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $k$ a field. I want to prove that $k[x,y]$ is not finitely generated as $k[x]$-module, that is I would like to prove that there are no $b_1, ... , b_n \in k[x,y]$ such that $k[x,y] = b_1 k[x] + ... + b_n k[x]$. I tried looking for a counterexample but I wasn’t able to find any. Any hints?

Comment: You can try to assume that you have a set of generators $p_1,...,p_n$, and notice that the action of $k[x]$ on these polynomials will not increase their $y$-degree. Take $m$ to be the maximal degree of the polynomials, and argue that $y^{m+1}$ is not generated by these generators.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking  of another approach: given that $k[x,y]$ is a finitely generated algebra over $k[x]$, could we also prove that $k[x,y]$ is not integral over $k[x]$? In fact for that matter, $y$ is not a root of any polynomial with coefficients in $k[x]$. Is It correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $p_1,\cdots, p_n\in k[x]$. Can you find an upper bound on $\deg_y(p_1b_1+\cdots+p_nb_n)$ which is independent on $p_1,\cdots, p_n$?

Comment: I just couldn't get that if $p_1, \cdots , p_n\in k[x]$, then how does $y$ appear in the linear combination $p_1b_1+\cdots+p_nb_n$  ?

Comment: @Why Simple: it appears in the $b_i$-s.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason as, for any commutative ring $R$, $R[X] $ is a free $R$-module, but not  a finitely generated one.